# Cross Origin Error on iframe with blob URL

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing, cross-domain

We have a url like 'https://www.example.com'

In the page we set the domain as `document.domain = example.com`

In the page, we need to print a pdf which we get from a web service so the code is like below.

```
requestPdf().then((pdfData) => {
   const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
   const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
   // pdfUrl is something like this:
   // blob:https://www.example.com/xyzc-wertas-asdre
   iframeElement.attribute('src', pdfUrl);
});
```

On this case, when we try to print iframe, we get cross domain error.
Is there a way to bypass this error?

Comment: We cannot communicate through javascript in case of cross domain(same-originn policy). document.domain only works for sub-domain. Please go through this -https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

Comment: You are right about this but these two domains are the same in this case. I believe the main problem is in the following link. Please check last paragraph of notes section on this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain